# Using only the field axioms of real numbers prove that $(-1)(-1) = 1$

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers, axioms

Using only the field axioms of real numbers prove that $(-1)(-1) = 1$ 
(1) I start with an obvious fact:$$0 = 0$$ 
(2) Add $(-1)$ to both sides of the equation:
$$0 + (-1) = 0+ (-1)$$
(3) Zero is the neutral element of addition
$$(-1) = (-1)$$
(4) One is the neutral element of multiplication 
$$(-1)(1) = (-1)$$
$$(-1)(1+(-1)+1)=(-1)$$
(5) Multiplication is distributive under addition
$$(-1)(1)+(-1)(-1)+(-1)(1) = (-1)$$
(6) One is the neutral element of multiplication
$$(-1)+(-1)(-1)+(-1)=(-1)$$
(7) Add $1$ to both sides
$$(-1)+(-1)(-1)+(-1)+1=(-1)+1$$
(8) Negative one is the additive inverse of one
$$(-1)+(-1)(-1) +0 = 0$$
(9) Add 1 to both sides
$$1 + (-1) + (-1)(-1)+0 = 0 + 1$$
$$0 + (-1)(-1) + 0 = 0 + 1$$
(10) Zero is the neutral element of addition
$$(-1)(-1) = 1$$
Is my proof good? Should I change something?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Is there any reason to start with $0=0$ and not with $(-1)=(-1)$?

Comment: This all looks right to me.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, 
Actually, I thought that it would be more natural.

Comment: how do you justify (2) and (7) and (9)?
Anyway maybe starting from $-1=-1$ is better

Comment: @Raffaele
Zero is the neutral element of addition, therefore $0 + (-1) = (-1)$ is rather obvious, am I wrong?

Comment: @Aemilius No, I mean adding the same quantity in right and left sides

Comment: @Raffaele
For every $x, y, z$ such that $x \le y$ <br> $x + z \le y+z$
This is true also when $x = y$

Comment: What *are* the field axioms for real numbers?  Is there a link with that list?

Comment: @Bram28 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Classic_definition

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of this?

*Lemma.*
In a field $a\cdot 0=0\cdot a=0$, for any $a\in\mathbb{F}$

*proof*

$a\cdot 0=a\cdot (1+(-1))=a+(-a)=0$

$0\cdot a=a\cdot 0=0$ for the commutativity of product

*end proof*

*end lemma*

*main proof*

$1=1\\
1+0\cdot 0=1\\
1+(1-1)(1-1)=1\\
1+1\cdot 1+1(-1)-1(1)+(-1)(-1)\\
1+1-1-1+(-1)(-1)=1\\
0+0+(-1)(-1)=1\\
(-1)(-1)=1$

Comment: Ridiculous though it may sound, how do you know that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$?

Comment: @Aemilius it's an issue of the other answerer, too :)

Comment: @Aemilius should work now. Have a look. Disclaimer: I am not saying your proof is bad. I just wanted to show mine.

Comment: Yeah, now this works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Some people like to condense these things into one string of equalities:

$$\begin{align}(-1)(-1)=(-1)(-1)+0 &= (-1)(-1)+(-1)+1\\
&= (-1)(-1)+(-1)(1)+1\\
&=(-1)(-1+1) + 1\\
&=(-1)(0) + 1\\
&=0+1\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

This is basically just your argument, rearranged. It begins with $(-1)(-1)$ and ends with $1$, and we can justify each equal sign along the way: i) $0$ is the additive identity, ii)$-1$ and $1$ are opposites, iii) $1$ is the multiplicative identity, iv) distribution, v) $-1$ and $1$ are opposites, vi) $0$ is an annihilator for multiplication, vii) $0$ is the additive identity.

The only step here that isn't an axiom is that $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a$, but this is usually one of the first things you prove.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to prove first $(-1)x=-x$. Since $-1+1=0=-1+(-(-1))$, this implies (as inverses are unique!) $1=-(-1)=(-1) (-1)$.