# Showing that $(-1)\cdot(-1) = 1$ in Field theory.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that

$(-a) = (-1)\cdot a$ and $-(-a) = a$

So that I could say $a=1$ and use this in:

$-(-a) = - [(-1)\cdot a]$

such that $1 = -[(-1)\cdot 1]$.

But I don't know how to proceed from here, how can I turn $-[(-1)\cdot 1]$ into a simple $(-1)\cdot (-1)$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can use `\cdot` for the multiplication dot.

Comment: What is the difference between $(-1)*(-1)$ and $(-1).(-1)$?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503351/using-only-the-field-axioms-of-real-numbers-prove-that-1-1-1). The proof is the same for every field.

Comment: choose $a=1$ for $-(-a) = a$ but choose $a=-1$ for $(-a) = (-1)*a$

Comment: $$\begin{align} (-1)(-1)&=(-1)(-1)+((-1)+1)\\&=(-1)(-1)+1(-1)+1\\&=((-1)+1)(-1)+1\\&=0\cdot (-1)+1\\&=0+1=1. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you know that

1. $-a=(-1)\cdot a$
2. $-(-a)=a$

Note that

$1=_2-(-1)=_1(-1)\cdot (-1)$

Comment: This is perfect, I am so dumb, could not see it for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see that $x^2=1$ has two solutions $1$ and $-1$ since a field is necessarily an integral domain.